# Preventing a laptop from being damaged by cold weather

Tags: laptop, battery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will cold weather break my laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/96313/will-cold-weather-break-my-laptop)

Every day I have to go to college with my Compaq-Presario CQ61-355SQ laptop and winter is closing in fast; I have to walk about 30 minutes to college.

Will my laptop break if I keep taking it from a cold environment to a warm environment and open it up immediately after I get there? I do not have the time to wait for it to warm up.

Is it a good idea to leave the laptop open while I walk to college so that it won't get cold?

What solution can I use to keep my laptop safe?

Comment: This wiki page http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Maintenance#Battery_treatment has some advice on battery treatment for different type of batteries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 7 years of university, carrying laptops (First a Samsung P10, then an X10+, then an N110) there every day even in really cold winders, I have never had a single problem with the cold/warm/cold changes. My GF carried two different MacBooks around every day, too.

I can understand the worry, but unless Compaqs are surprisingly bad in build quality, I had virtually closed and rather open-cased (the N110 has slits everywhere ;) ) machines and never even notices signs of any trouble. Should be safe. ^_^

(edit)
As far as the battery is concerned, when really cold they have a higher internal resistance and hence run dry faster. In turn they self-discharge less quickly. No permanent damage unless you are working at the south pole, however.